# IE8 print shrink to fit not working

Tags: printing, internet-explorer-8

IE8 print "shrink to fit" option is not working and the answer they gave on the microsoft support forum is this one:

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/printing-problems-in-internet-explorere-8-will-not/8ca793aa-1a0b-42cc-9ec3-720a595c3874

Does anyone know what "Some webpages specify exactly where text should print on the page" means? or how can I fix this shrink to fit issue on IE8 without changing the browser mode to compatibility?

On some pages shrink to fit works, on others it doesn't work, so my guess is that I'm using some CSS that may be related to this matter: "Some webpages specify exactly where text should print on the page", and I want to remove it so "shrink to fit" works again, but don't know exactly which codes causes this problem.

Thank you